# How to change elements of an array field to values of a dict with a single attribute in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I need a way to change the elements of an array field to values of a dict with a single attribute.  I don't have to write the result back into my table.  I just have to read it that way.

My table has rows like this :

```
{a: 1, b:[ {...}, ..., {...} ], c: 2}
```

I need a query that returns each row rewritten like this :

```
{a: 1, b: [ {foo: { ... }}, ..., {foo: {...}} ], c: 2}
```

In other words, each element of `b` becomes a dict with a single attribute, `foo`.

This feels like a job for `$project` or `$replaceRoot` or `$set`.

I'm using MongoDB 4.2.2 and PyMongo 3.10.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Hi welcome to Stackoverflow, please share code you already have.

Comment: @David Talmage : Do you've to update it back ?  If yes is it for entire collection ? Also what's your MongoDB version ?

Comment: @whoami I updated my question to answer your questions.  TL;DR: No, I don't have to update it back.  MongoDB 4.4.2.

Comment: @David Talmage : unfortunately there is no `MongoDB v4.4.2`, latest major version is `4.2` which is released couple of months back, Anyway please check my answer we can do this even on older version..

Comment: @whoam Oops.  A typo.  I corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using aggregation :

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$addFields : {b : { $map: { input: '$b', in: {foo : '$$this'} } }}}])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uaODHQDumgr)

**Ref :** [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) , [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html)

Comment: Thank you @whoami.  This is exactly what I need.