# Pipeline to add an attribute to each document in an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, dictionary, aggregation

I need a way to add an attribute to each document in an array of documents in an aggregation pipeline.  The value of the attribute comes from values in the array.  My collection has rows like these:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': [{ 'this': 'A', 'that': 'B', 'other': 'C' }], 'c': 2}, 
{'a': 3, 'b': [{ 'this': 'D', 'that': 'E', 'other': 'F' }, {'this': 'G', 'that': 'H', 'other': 'I'}], 'c': 4}
```

I want to turn each 'b' into an array of documents with two attributes, 'foo' and 'bar'. Each element of 'b' will become 'foo'.  The value of 'bar' is an object with an attribute whose value comes from the 'A' attribute of 'foo'.

I don't want to write the result back into the collection.

Here are the transformations I want to make:

```
{ "a" : 1, "b" : [ { "bar": { "this_value": "A"}, "foo" : { "this" : "A", "that" : "B", "other" : "C" } } ], "c" : 2 }
{ "a" : 3, "b" : [ { "bar": { "this_value": "D"}, "foo" : { "this" : "D", "that" : "E", "other" : "F" } }, { "bar" : { "this_value": "G" }, "foo" : { "this" : "G", "that" : "H", "other" : "I" } } ], "c" : 4 }
```

In [How to change elements of an array field to values of a dict with a single attribute in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60173702/how-to-change-elements-of-an-array-field-to-values-of-a-dict-with-a-single-attri)
, I learned how to construct the "foo" attributes:

```
t.aggregate( [{$addFields: {'b': { $map: { input: '$b', in: {'foo': '$$this'}}}}} ] )
```

I'm stuck on how to add the "bar" attributes.

Here are the Mongo Shell commands to create my collection and the "foo" part of the transformation:

```
c = new Mongo()
db = c.getDB('playful')
t = db['things']
t.insertMany([{'a': 1, 'b': [{ 'this': 'A', 'that': 'B', 'other': 'C' }], 'c': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': [{ 'this': 'D', 'that': 'E', 'other': 'F' }, {'this': 'G', 'that': 'H', 'other': 'I'}], 'c': 4}])
t.aggregate( [{$addFields: {'b': { $map: { input: '$b', in: {'foo': '$$this'}}}}} ] )
```

I'm using MongoDB 4.2.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply construct your bar object where you do it for foo :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "b": {
        $map: {
          input: "$b",
          in: {
            "foo": "$$this",
            "bar": {
              this_value: "$$this.this"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can test it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5GJIPVkARcw)